# Image rotation not working as expected

Tags: python, pygame

I am very new to python/pygame, and would like some help. I am trying to make  two cars automatically move forward(which I have completed successfully) however I cannot manage to make the cars turn left/right when a certain key is pressed. I would love someone to help me with this. As I said, I am new to this, so if anyone was kind enough to help, please can you edit my code so it is successful as well as an explanation to what is going wrong, thank you so very much in advance. https://i.stack.imgur.com/zrlUT.png
         https://i.stack.imgur.com/q6Hb9.png
         https://i.stack.imgur.com/MGR3N.jpg

P.S. There is no error message to my code, as there is no wrong in it, the rotate function is simply not working

```
import pygame
import sys
pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1150, 800))



pygame.display.set_caption("Car Football")

degrees = 180

x = 70
y = 70

x1 = 1000
y1 = 400

width = 70
height = 70


vel = 15
vel1 = 15

def rotatedleft():
    pygame.transform.rotate(redcar, (15))

def rotatedright():
     pygame.transform.rotate(redcar, (-15))



run = True
while run:
pygame.time.delay(100)

for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
        run = False

screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
bgImg = pygame.image.load("Football_pitch.png").convert()
screen.blit(bgImg, [0,0])
redcar = pygame.image.load("redcar.png")
screen.blit(redcar, (x, y))


keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
if keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
    rotatedleft = True
if run:
    x += vel

if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
    rotatedright = True



pygame.display.flip()
pygame.display.update()

for event in pygame.event.get():
     if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
         run = False
keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
if run:
     x1 -= vel1
if keys[pygame.K_d] and x1 < 1150:
     x1 += vel1
if keys[pygame.K_w]:
     y1 -= vel1
if keys[pygame.K_s]:
    y1 += vel1


bluecar = pygame.image.load("Bluecarss.png")
screen.blit(bluecar, (x1, y1))
circleball = pygame.draw.circle(screen, (255, 255, 255), (300, 140), 50, 0)
pygame.display.update()





pygame.display.flip()
pygame.quit()
sys.exit()
```

Comment: The indentation of your code is all messed-up and can't be run for that reason. Please [edit] your question and fix it—correct indentation is extremely important in Python code.

Comment: Sorry, I indented it correctly in my project, I messed up a bit whilst copying and pasting it here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to know trigonometry or [vectors](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/math.html#pygame.math.Vector2) if you want to rotate a car in your game and move it in the direction it is facing (I'm using vectors in the following example). The position and the velocity should be vectors and you have to add the `vel` to the `pos` vector every frame to move the car forward. You also need a [`pygame.Rect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html) which is used as the blit position (the rect makes it easier to center the car and can be used for collision detection).

When the user presses ← or →, you have to rotate the `angle` and the `vel` vector (`vel` is also the direction) and then use the angle to rotate the image/pygame.Surface. As for the image rotation, you should keep a reference to the original image in order to preserve the quality of the image. Pass it to `pygame.transform.rotate` together with the current angle of the car and you'll get a rotated surface. This surface will have different dimensions, so you need to create a new rect (with `pygame.Surface.get_rect`) to update the blit position (top left coordinates).

```
import pygame
from pygame.math import Vector2


pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1150, 800))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()  # A clock to limit the frame rate.
# Load your images once at the beginning of the program.
REDCAR_ORIGINAL = pygame.Surface((50, 30), pygame.SRCALPHA)
pygame.draw.polygon(
    REDCAR_ORIGINAL, (200, 0, 0), [(0, 0), (50, 10), (50, 20), (0, 30)])
redcar = REDCAR_ORIGINAL

# Use vectors for the position and the velocity.
pos = Vector2(70, 70)  # Center position of the car.
vel = Vector2(2, 0)
# This rect serves as the blit position of the redcar image.
rect = redcar.get_rect(center=pos)
angle = 0  # Current angle of the car.

run = True
while run:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
        # When a key gets pressed, increment the angle, rotate
        # the vector and create a new rotated car image.
        # The angle is rotated in the opposite direction because
        # pygame's y-axis is flipped.
        angle += 3
        vel.rotate_ip(-3)
        redcar = pygame.transform.rotate(REDCAR_ORIGINAL, angle)
        # Also, get a new rect because the image size was changed.
        # Pass the pos vector as the `center` argument to keep the
        # image centered.
        rect = redcar.get_rect(center=pos)
    elif keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
        angle -= 3
        vel.rotate_ip(3)
        redcar = pygame.transform.rotate(REDCAR_ORIGINAL, angle)
        rect = redcar.get_rect(center=pos)

    # Move the car by adding the velocity to the position.
    pos += vel
    rect.center = pos  # Update the rect as well.

    screen.fill((30, 30, 30))
    screen.blit(redcar, rect)  # Blit the car at the `rect.topleft` coords.

    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(60)  # Limit the frame rate to 60 FPS.

pygame.quit()
```

Comment: That was extremely helpful so thanks, now I can add a background and other things e.t.c

Answer (score 0):

```
if keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
    rotatedleft = True
```

You're assigning `True` to `rotatedleft`, which you've previously defined as a function, try calling the function, like so:

```
if keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
    rotatedleft()
```

Now it's kinda turning, I'm pretty sure it's still not quite what you're looking for but hey, baby steps. Best of luck with your game.

```
import pygame
import sys
pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1150, 800))



pygame.display.set_caption("Car Football")

degrees = 180

x = 70
y = 70

x1 = 1000
y1 = 400

width = 70
height = 70


vel = 15
vel1 = 15


run = True
while run:
    pygame.time.delay(100)

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

    screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
    bgImg = pygame.image.load("Football_pitch.png").convert()
    screen.blit(bgImg, [0,0])
    redcar = pygame.image.load("redcar.png")
    screen.blit(redcar, (x, y))


    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
        redcar = pygame.transform.rotate(redcar, 15)
        screen.blit(redcar, (x, y))

    if run:
        x += vel

    if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
        redcar = pygame.transform.rotate(redcar, -15)
        screen.blit(redcar, (x, y))



    pygame.display.flip()
    pygame.display.update()

    for event in pygame.event.get():
         if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
             run = False
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if run:
         x1 -= vel1
    if keys[pygame.K_d] and x1 < 1150:
         x1 += vel1
    if keys[pygame.K_w]:
         y1 -= vel1
    if keys[pygame.K_s]:
        y1 += vel1


    bluecar = pygame.image.load("Bluecarss.png")
    screen.blit(bluecar, (x1, y1))
    circleball = pygame.draw.circle(screen, (255, 255, 255), (300, 140), 50, 0)
    pygame.display.update()





pygame.display.flip()
pygame.quit()
sys.exit()
```

Comment: Can you share your image files? I can't run it without them.

Comment: Ok, I've added them. Sorry I have to make it into a link, I don't have 10 Stack Overflow reputation as I've only started now.

Comment: I've edited my post, I dunno if you get notified of that.

Comment: Thank you so much for your time and help